# Find the framework behind a website?

Tags: magento, web-scraping

I use Python and BeautifulSoup. Is there a way I could tell if a particular website is running `Magento` platform?

[Magento eCommerce Platform](http://magento.com/)

Comment: this question seems off topic.. since it is not related to Magento coding, rather seems that a general query.

Comment: Yes, I am not talking particularly about Magento. I named it just to explain myself in a better way. I wanted to know how to analyze a website to find the underlying backend.

Answer (score 4):

How to Find CMS, Platform or Technology used by a Website?

Chrome Extensions to find CMS/Platform of a Website
Firefox Addons to find CMS/Platform of a Website

1. **CMS Detector**
   Online Webtools has got a very nice CMS detector application which can be used just to find out the Content Management System used by a website or Framework used by a site.
2. **Builtwith (Most Popular and Effective)**
   Builtwith is a very powerful tool to determine a site framework. Builtwith goes deep and throws you the more in-depth detail of a website including Server information, Content Management System, Framework, Advertising used, Analytics and tracking, Javascript libraries, Audio/Video media, Widgets used, Content Delivery Network, Aggregation Functionality, Document Information and Encoding type.
3. **W3Techs (Popular and Highly Effective)**
   W3Techs gives the complete detail of a website. The details include Website background, Content Management System, Server side programming languages, Client side programming languages, Javascript library, Mark-up language, Character Encoding, Image file formats, Site elements, SSL Certificate authorities, Social Widgets, Web server, Traffic Analysis tools, Advertising network, Domain, Language and Technology Score. The tool gives ultimate in-depth data of a website which is extremely useful for a programmer. This tools is also available as Browser Extensions for Chrome and Firefox.
4. **Guess Scritch**
   This tool analyzes websites and attempts to detect the plaform, language, tools, widgets, trackers and javascript/css frameworks and other technologies used for any website. This is a great tool to determine the CMS of a website.
   Guess Scritch
5. **WhatCMS** WhaCMS just displays the Content Management System used in a website and doesn’t analyze any other information. If you only need to lookup a website platform in which it is built, then this toll is of great help.
6. **CMSEYE**
   This tool seems to be down/unavailable
7. **W3Techs**
   This extension is probably the best one to analyze various aspects of a website. W3Techs gives the complete detail of a website. The details include Website background, Content Management System, Server side programming languages, Client side programming languages, Javascript library, Mark-up language, Character Encoding, Image file formats, Site elements, SSL Certificate authorities, Social Widgets, Web server, Traffic Analysis tools, Advertising network, Domain, Language and Technology Score. The tool gives ultimate in-depth data of a website which is extremely useful for a programmer.
   This tool just shows up the CMS of a website.
8. **Chrome Sniffer**
   This extension will help web developer to inspect web framework / CMS and javascript library running on current browsing website. An icon will appear on address bar indicates the detected framework. Currently, this extension can detect more than 100 popular CMS and javascript libraries.
9. **Wappalyzer**
   Wappalyzer uncovers the technologies used on websites. It detects content management systems, web shops, web servers, JavaScript frameworks, analytics tools and many more.

check this **[link](http://thetechgears.com/how-to-find-what-cms-platform-or-framework-a-website-is-using/)**.. will help you

Comment: Thanks.. I don't mean to use available tools.. I wanted to do the analysis myself..

Comment: Nothing of mentioned links works properly, I have bootstrap 3 (obvious) and no tool can detect it, furthermore they do not detect Rails (all assume PHP) and assume nginx server (in fact it is passenger) so to summarize all are fake and unreliable sites.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to find whether a site is running on Magento or not.

- Check page source of any page, if it has like **skin/frontend**
- In address bar, open url /downloader, if it opens magento connect login page
- In address bar, open url /install.php, if site is Magento site, then it will show following error:

  FAILED ERROR: Magento is already installed
- Another clue can be admin url. Most of Magento stores don't bother to change admin url. If it opens by hitting /index.php/admin and shows Magento somewhere on page, then it is 100% running on Magento Platform.

I hope, this will help you.